# Use TIdCmdTCPServer for binary data?

Tags: c++, c++builder, indy, indy10

I have a TCP server in my Windows application based on `TIdCmdTCPServer` and it has been performing great. Now I have a device that does not send text string but binary data. I really don't want to rewrite my working code to use `TIdTCPServer`.

Is there any way I can use my current code and grab the discarded data somewhere, i.e. can I have access to the raw data received without interfering with other connections that use text?

I tried the `OnBeforeCommandHandler` event, but it already seems to assume the data is a string (i.e. cuts off at the first zero byte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdCmdTCPServer` does not stop reading on nul bytes, like you claim.  By default, it reads each command by calling `TIdIOHandler.ReadLn()`, which reads until a `(CR+)LF` is received.  However, the `TIdIOHandler.DefStringEncoding` is set to US-ASCII by default, so that could be causing data loss when reading binary data as a string.

That being said, `TIdCmdTCPServer` is designed primarily for textual commands.  By default, tt cannot receive binary commands, or binary parameters.  However, if the binary data follows a textual command, your `TIdCommandHandler.OnCommand` event handlers can read the binary data after the command has been received, by simply reading the binary using the `ASender.Context.Connection.IOHandler` as needed.

Otherwise, if that does not suit your needs (because the binary commands are not in a format that would normally trigger an `OnCommand` event), you will have to derive a new class from `TIdCmdTCPServer` and have it either:

- override the virtual `ReadCommandLine()` method to read a binary command and its parameters from the `Connection` and return that data in a `string` format of your choosing (you can use Indy's `IndyTextEncoding_8bit` encoding, or `BytesToStringRaw()` function, to help you with that, or use whatever `string` format you want). And then define a `CommandHandler` to match that stringified command.
- override the virtual `DoExecute()` method, then you have full control over the reading of the `Connection` and can handle commands however you want.  To trigger `OnCommand` events, call the server's `CommandHandlers.HandleCommand()` method passing it `string` values of your choosing.

Personally, I would not recommend mixing textual and non-textual clients on the same server.  They are clearly using different protocols, so you should be using different servers on different ports to handle them separately.